# jQuery : Accordion and tabs in 2 fixed columns

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 columns in the first one an accordion, in the second some tabs. The problem I have is the section of the tab where the level is, is big, Take a look the picture.

I join the code :
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14486902/jQuery.2FixedColumns.Tabs.Accordion.rar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this into a jsfiddle.  [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/JzWWd/) an example of both working side-by-side.  My bet is that you have the tabs and the accordion in one table row, and the tab content in a different table row.

Answer (score 0):

the clearfix seems to be messing it up. if you use inspect element (firebug or in chrome) you can de-select clearfix(all instances of it on the ul) and you'll see it adjust